# AWS Amplify Cognito Auth signOut Token does not have required scopes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I trying to signOut and Revoke all Tokens used in the session so for that I trying to use: `Auth.signOut({ global: true })` As docs refer but getting `Token does not have required scopes`

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function signOut() {
    try {
        await Auth.signOut({ global: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing out: ', error);
    }
}
```

I setup `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` as follows:

[image]

Any idea Why this is happening?

Comment: I got same issue, you must check token(id, access) with scope respective. openid with idToken, and aws.cognito.signin.user.admin for access token

Comment: @VũMinhVương Thanks, Any tutorial or steps to do that?

Comment: so sorry for no check your comment. I just discover based in test several case. So, I have no document for that.